# Xcodebuild'ing a workspace and setting a custom build path

Tags: workspace, xcodebuild

I'm trying to use `xcodebuild` to build a multi-project project in a workspace. When XCode builds a workspace it automatically places all build artifacts in a common directory in DerivedData so that each project can access it dependencies.

If I use this command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace -schema builtIt -configuration Release
```

Eveything works, but the artifacts are placed in usual derived data directory. I want then to appear in a specific directory which I can access from CI builds. So I tried this

```
xcodebuild -workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace -schema builtIt -configuration Release SYMROOT=build/products OBJROOT=build/intermediates
```

However xcodebuild fails with this saying

```
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/d4rkf1br3/projects/dNodi/build/intermediates/dNodi.build/Debug-iphoneos/dNodi.build/StaticAnalyzer/normal/armv7/DNRootSelector.d''. 
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “DNRootSelector.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." 
UserInfo=0x4012fea40 {NSFilePath=/Users/d4rkf1br3/projects/dNodi/build/intermediates/dNodi.build/Debug-iphoneos/dNodi.build/StaticAnalyzer/normal/armv7/DNRootSelector.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x4012fc240 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. 
User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/d4rkf1br3/projects/dNodi/build/intermediates/dNodi.build/Debug-iphoneos/dNodi.build/StaticAnalyzer/normal/armv7/DNRootSelector.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}
```

The problem appears to be that xcodebuild is no longer using a central directory for all projects in the workspace and is storing the artifacts in each project instead. Hence it cannot locate the dependencies between code being compiled and artifacts produced in other projects.

Does anyone know the correct parameter to set on the command line?

Xcode's Build Setting Reference has not been updated for two years so I don't know if there are new build settings I can apply.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a new option but the 5.0 release of `xcodebuild` has an option `-derivedDataPath` which allows you to specify the directory you'd like all the build products to sit in.

For instance, passing `-derivedDataPath build` creates the folder `build` relative to where you ran `xcodebuild` from, and you can find your app predictably in a subfolder like `build/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos`.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html

Comment: Setting this as the accepted answer because XCode 5 handles command line builds much better.

Comment: I was using CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="$WORKSPACE/Build" OBJROOT="$WORKSPACE/Build"  SYMROOT=$WORKSPACE/Build DSTROOT=$WORKSPACE/Build -destination   for my builds -derivedDataPath fixed lots of random issues I was seeing.

Comment: This worked for my situation; building my own frameworks that depend on my other frameworks. The parameter after `-derivedDataPath` can be named whatever you want. I also completely removed `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` which worked when building for devices but not for simulators.

Answer (score 22):

The best solution i have found so far is to use the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` parameter with an ABSOLUTE path (e.g. /tmp/$PROJECT/build). Like this:

```
xcodebuild -scheme "scheme" -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$ABSOLUTE_BUILD_PATH
```

I use Jenkins and there I have an variable named `$WORKSPACE`. With `$WORKSPACE/build` as my `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` I have a solution I'm happy with.

The relative paths don't seem to work as expected. We should file a bug report.

Comment: I've found the same thing. Setting the BUILD_DIR or CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR with a relative path works for the main project, but subprojects go to the wrong place. Using absolute paths solves this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It overwrites my custom xcconfig files in xcworkspace.

Answer (score 9):

I also met this problem when I build my project from Jenkins CI tool. My main project depends a sub-project. I have tried building follow @Chilloutman's solution like this:

```
xcodebuild -target TravelGuideMdd -sdk iphoneos -configuration DailyBuild clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/mobileserver/jenkins_home/jobs/TravelGuide-Buid-For-Me/workspace/build BUILD_DIR =/Users/mobileserver/jenkins_home/jobs/TravelGuide-Buid-For-Me/workspace/build
```

or

```
xcodebuild -target TravelGuideMdd -sdk iphoneos -configuration DailyBuild clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/mobileserver/jenkins_home/jobs/TravelGuide-Buid-For-Me/workspace/build
```

Both of them occur errors `Could not find iphoneos in /Users/mobileserver/jenkins_home/jobs/TravelGuide-Buid-For-Me/workspace/build`

But I get success finally using this:

```
xcodebuild -target TravelGuideMdd -sdk iphoneos6.1 -configuration DailyBuild clean build SYMROOT=/Users/mobileserver/jenkins_home/jobs/TravelGuide-Buid-For-Me/workspace/build
```

That is: Setting the SYMROOT with a absolute paths.

Comment: Thanks very much, this also fixed this issue for me (in case this isn't working for others, I couldn't make it work until I noticed that in this version, SYMROOT has to be used _without_ any other BUILD_DIR or CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR arguments). I think the marked correct answer might not be applicable to Xcode 5's behavior.

Comment: From the current docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_DO_I_BUILD_MY_PROJECTS_FROM_THE_COMMAND_LINE_) this looks like the correct approach.

Comment: I have recently been trying a command line build that also exports an archive. When I tried using SYMROOT that resulted in incomplete results in the archive folder. Specifying the OBJROOT parameter and the -archivePath worked for me.  I didn't try combining it with -derivedDataPath.